# ConstraintLayout very slow in my Tablet

Tags: android

I am android developer. 
mostly, I used ConstraintLayout for performance.
but, My app is slower than original project.
main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline0"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/intro_logo"
            android:id="@+id/introLogo"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#23314d"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline0">
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kisanLogo"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kisanLogo"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kisanLogo"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view4"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kisanLogo"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kisanLogo"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kisanLogo"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kisanLogo"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/realCountInformation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_main_count_information"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/realCountInformationTv"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideHori1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showingCoutLog"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_main_showing_count_log"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/showingCoutLogTv"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideHori1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showingAdvertisement"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_main_showing_advertisement"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/showingAdvertisementTv"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideHori1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/configureAdvertisement"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_main_configure_advertisement"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/configureAdvertisementTv"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideHori1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/userManagement"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_main_user_management"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/userManagementTv"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideHori1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/configure"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_main_configure"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/configureTv"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideHori1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/realCountInformationTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/real_time_counting"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_intro_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideHori2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/realCountInformation" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showingCoutLogTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/count_history"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_intro_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideHori2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/showingCoutLog" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showingAdvertisementTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/view_ad"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_intro_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideHori2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/showingAdvertisement" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/configureAdvertisementTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ad_setting"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_intro_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideHori2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/configureAdvertisement" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userManagementTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/user_management"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_intro_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideHori2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userManagement" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/configureTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/setting"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_intro_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideHori2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/configure" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kisanLogo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/kisan_logo"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideHori2"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideHori1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideHori2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This code is very slow in my tablet(cheap). 
how to increases my app performance and why is it so slow?
The loading time of this app is 2~5 seconds in my tablet.
It is serious. I want to increase performance the layout. 
how to change my code of above code.

Comment: reduce the number of layouts. FYI constraint layout is combination of linear and relative layouts so It's will take some time to align the views

Comment: can you add your design screen?